# Radiobutton data want to be send to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to send the checked radiobutton data in an asp page using c# insertion command to the SQL Server 2005

plz tell me in details

Thanks,
Churchill

Comment: You are going to have to give a lot more detail than that. What is the table schema liek that you are using, what have you tried so far?

Comment: What you mean by radio button data please be specific about your question and describe more to get the answer

Comment: on an asp page i need to select a gender which value would be passed to the database ... and i'm using asp.net as front end c# for writing codes & sqlserver2005 as backend

Comment: i have taken 2 radio button Male & Female. if any 1 of them is selected then that value need to be passed to the database

Comment: What have you done so far?  Post your current approach and then we can advise on a solution.

Comment: i'm have taken two radionbuttons male & Female on the webpage.
i have made the connection through the connection methods now if i'm selecting  any 1 of the radio button then that data need to be passed to the database but i cant able to send the data to the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just insert it by writing an insert query......you need to write this in your value..........'"+RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue+"'

Comment: thank U shruti thanku So much ur syntax helped me in successfully inserting the data into the databse ..thank u